# How to connect to influxDB in version 2.0

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql, influxdb-python, flux-influxdb

After running influxd daemon when I try to start influx as in older version I'm not able to connect any CLI interface for DB.
Instead it is showing help commands.
Can anyone please help here

Answer (score 0):

Connect to port 8086 of the machine you installed influx on, to communicate via the web based interface and play with queries in the Explore section.

Alternatively, you can interact via the CLI using the influx command only if you're on the same machine as the installation - those are the help commands you're seeing - there's no REPL style interaction in v2.

(Well, unless you build and install the Flux REPL available [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/tools/repl/) - everything you do here you can also do via the Influx UI I mentioned above via a web session on port 8086.)